# Apps that contain empty iAd banners will be rejected

Tags: iphone, screenshot, iad, banner-ads

I have just had my app rejected based on the fact that my screenshots show empty iAd banners. I want to fix this but I'm unsure of what needs to be done. Should I...

A) Create screenshots with ACTUAL iAds?

B) Create new screenshots with the iAd banner not showing?

C) Some other option...

Please can you provide details on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the screenshots of popular (or unpopular) free apps on the App Store?

Comment: I have tried this but it looks like some apps seem to have the iAd test apps banner in place. I've just removed the ad banners and tried re-submitting it. Hopefully that will work.

Comment: Removing the ads worked (I just set it to airplane mode to achieve this).

Comment: Consider helping future visitors to StackOverflow by writing an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by removing the ad's from my screenshots (I just set the device to airplane mode to hide them).

My app has now been approved and is on sale.

Answer (score 0):

What I wind up doing for this is disabling the iAd code in my app when I'm doing certain builds, including the build for generating screenshots. It's an automatic part of my build process so there's no futzing with the simulator or a real device tricking it into not showing ads.